# How to retrieve hadoop job map/reduce input/output count

Tags: hadoop

Is there any way to retrieve and print the number of reduce output records after running a hadoop job?
I'm iteratively running a map-reduce and I want to stop when my previous reduce output count is same as current map output count.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Hadoop version, the names can be different. 
But in general you can access your counters from the job object.

```
job.getCounters().findCounter("org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter", 
           "REDUCE_OUTPUT_RECORDS").getValue();
```

Consult the WebUI to see what counters are defined in your job, change the names accordingly.

Comment: Can I use this same one for python?

Comment: entirely depends how you submit your job from python?

Comment: How to read counters in Hadoop Streaming using Python? Cannot find any information on the Internet.